# Can BSSID be used as an unique identifier?

Tags: android, networking

I'm building an Android App that lists all wifi networks arround the user.

My app requires the informations about the user's network when he tries to use an specific service.

When my app gets all the informations from the user's network, it automatically inserts on my database table a new row, with all these necessary informations.

The issue that I'm having is that I don't know if all Wifi networks got an unique identifier. I will save everything on my Database, and some Wifi informations aren't unique, like the SSID

So, I would like to know if BSSID can be used as an unique ID, because I will have to compare every network.

I will check if a network is on my Database checking if the BSSID value is on my database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BSSID in a beacon frame should be good enough to identify unique access points as it is actually the MAC address. Normally it is unique for every NIC. However, somebody could implement there own access point with a device that allows manual change of the NIC's MAC address, this is not the case in typical access point devices but something knowledgeable people can do.

However, you must know that two AP's with different BSSID's (different Basic Service Sets) can belong to the same WLAN, with the same SSID. This is when 2 or more BSS's form an Extended Service Set (ESS)