# Flutter: How to detect my office Wi-Fi connection

Tags: flutter, connection, wifi

Can Flutter detect that I'm using a Wi-Fi connection in my office? So, suppose I am connected to Wi-Fi in the office, the application will detect it. However, the application can still be run using any connection.

Comment: you can check this package https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity, although it will only tell if you're on mobile data, wifi or no connection. i don't it will tell specific wifi details AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of you who answered. After I found out from [Can BSSID be used as an unique identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524769/can-bssid-be-used-as-an-unique-identifier), then I use the [wifi_info_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_plugin) plugin. I use the BSSID or what is called the WLAN MAC Address, the BSSID is unique enough to be used as a detector.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF

Please check this package : https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot

Some options are not available on iOS, but it may be fair enough for you.